# Call a function when "event.GetFrom(m_cpVoice)==S_OK" (ergo when event happens) [SAPI 5.1 and C++]

Tags: c++, events, event-handling, sapi

I'm doing a project with a 3D model, that speaks. 
So, I'm using SAPI 5.1, and I want to call a function asynchronously when there's a Viseme event (in order to play the animation related to).

How could I do it?

Thank you very much.

Note: I use : hRes = m_cpVoice->Speak(L"All I want is to solve this problem", SPF_ASYNC , NULL); 
      And I know the CspEvent, event.eEventId . All I want is how to call a function when Sapi    event happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to call [m_cpVoice->SetInterest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717856(v=VS.85).aspx)(SPFEI([SPEI_VISEME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717254(v=VS.85).aspx)), SPFEI(SPEI_VISEME)); that will tell SAPI to send an event when a VISEME event fires.

Second, you need to set up an event handler by calling [m_cpVoice->SetNotifyCallbackInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717975(v=VS.85).aspx), with your callback.  (It must implement [ISpNotifyCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717944(v=VS.85).aspx), which is a virtual C++ interface that your object would implement.)

You can look at the [SAPI events documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720164(VS.85).aspx) for more details.

A sample implementation of ISpNotifyCallback would look like this:

TTSHandler.h:

```
class CTTSHandler : ISpNotifyCallback
{
public:
    CTTSHandler(void);
    ~CTTSHandler(void);
    HRESULT Initialize();
    HRESULT DoSpeak();
    HRESULT Uninitialize();

private:
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE NotifyCallback(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    void TTSAppStatusMessage(LPCTSTR str);

    CComPtr<ISpAudio>   m_cpOutAudio;
    CComPtr<ISpVoice> m_cpVoice;
    HANDLE m_hSpeakDone;
};
```

TTSHandler.cpp:

```
#include "TTSHandler.h"
#include <sphelper.h>

CTTSHandler::CTTSHandler(void) : m_hSpeakDone(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
}

CTTSHandler::~CTTSHandler(void)
{
}

HRESULT CTTSHandler::Initialize()
{
    HRESULT hr = m_cpVoice.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_SpVoice );
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        SpCreateDefaultObjectFromCategoryId( SPCAT_AUDIOOUT, &m_cpOutAudio );
    }
    if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        hr = m_cpVoice->SetOutput( m_cpOutAudio, FALSE );
    }
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        hr = m_cpVoice->SetNotifyCallbackInterface(this, 0, 0);
    }
    // We're interested in all TTS events
    if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        hr = m_cpVoice->SetInterest( SPFEI_ALL_TTS_EVENTS, SPFEI_ALL_TTS_EVENTS );
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        m_hSpeakDone = ::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);     // anonymous event used to wait for speech done
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT CTTSHandler::DoSpeak()
{
    HRESULT hr = m_cpVoice->Speak( L"This is a reasonably long string that should take a while to speak.  This is some more text.", SPF_ASYNC |SPF_IS_NOT_XML, 0 );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        TTSAppStatusMessage(  _T("speak failed\r\n") );
    }
    else
    {
        BOOL fContinue = TRUE;
        while (fContinue)
        {
            DWORD dwWaitId = ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, &m_hSpeakDone, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT, MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE);
            switch (dwWaitId)
            {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                {
                    fContinue = FALSE;
                }
                break;

            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
                {
                    MSG Msg;
                    while (::PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
                    {
                        ::TranslateMessage(&Msg);
                        ::DispatchMessage(&Msg);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                {
                    hr = S_FALSE;
                    fContinue = FALSE;
                }
                break;

            default:// Unexpected error
                {
                    TTSAppStatusMessage(L"Unexpected error returned from MsgWaitForMultipleObj");
                    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(::GetLastError());
                    fContinue = FALSE;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT CTTSHandler::Uninitialize()
{
    m_cpVoice = NULL;
    return S_OK;
}


void CTTSHandler::TTSAppStatusMessage(LPCTSTR szMessage )
{
    wprintf_s(L"%s", szMessage);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CTTSHandler::NotifyCallback(WPARAM, LPARAM)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Handles the WM_TTSAPPCUSTOMEVENT application defined message and all
// of it's appropriate SAPI5 events.
//
{

    CSpEvent        event;  // helper class in sphelper.h for events that releases any 
    // allocated memory in it's destructor - SAFER than SPEVENT
    int             i = 0;
    HRESULT         hr = S_OK;

    while( event.GetFrom(m_cpVoice) == S_OK )
    {
        switch( event.eEventId )
        {
        case SPEI_START_INPUT_STREAM:
            TTSAppStatusMessage(  _T("StartStream event\r\n") );
            break; 

        case SPEI_END_INPUT_STREAM:
            TTSAppStatusMessage(  _T("EndStream event\r\n") );
            SetEvent(m_hSpeakDone);
            break;     

        case SPEI_VOICE_CHANGE:
            TTSAppStatusMessage(  _T("Voicechange event\r\n") );
            break;

        case SPEI_TTS_BOOKMARK:
            {
                // Get the string associated with the bookmark
                // and add the null terminator.
                TCHAR szBuff2[MAX_PATH] = _T("Bookmark event: ");

                size_t cEventString = wcslen( event.String() ) + 1;
                WCHAR *pwszEventString = new WCHAR[ cEventString ];
                if ( pwszEventString )
                {
                    wcscpy_s( pwszEventString, cEventString, event.String() );
                    _tcscat_s( szBuff2, _countof(szBuff2), CW2T(pwszEventString) );
                    delete[] pwszEventString;
                }

                _tcscat_s( szBuff2, _countof(szBuff2), _T("\r\n") );
                TTSAppStatusMessage(  szBuff2 );
            }
            break;

        case SPEI_WORD_BOUNDARY:
            TTSAppStatusMessage(  _T("Wordboundary event\r\n") );
            break;

        case SPEI_PHONEME:
            TTSAppStatusMessage(  _T("Phoneme event\r\n") );
            break;

        case SPEI_VISEME:
            TTSAppStatusMessage(  _T("Viseme event\r\n") );
            break;

        case SPEI_SENTENCE_BOUNDARY:
            TTSAppStatusMessage(  _T("Sentence event\r\n") );
            break;

        case SPEI_TTS_AUDIO_LEVEL:
            WCHAR wszBuff[MAX_PATH];
            swprintf_s(wszBuff, _countof(wszBuff), L"Audio level: %d\r\n", (ULONG)event.wParam);
            TTSAppStatusMessage(  CW2T(wszBuff) );
            break;

        case SPEI_TTS_PRIVATE:
            TTSAppStatusMessage(  _T("Private engine event\r\n") );
            break;

        default:
            TTSAppStatusMessage(  _T("Unknown message\r\n") );
            break;
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

 I have a problem with the second part. SetNotifyCallbackInterface uses as first parametrer "ISpNotifyCallback* " and a don't know how to implement this. I have looked for it on Sapi events documentation, but I definitely don't know how to do it. (Sapi headers neither says anything about it.

 I'm a bit lost, so I would apreciate so much a little explanation.
 Thanks again

Comment: The MSDN docs pretty much say it all: "This is a C++ virtual interface that can be implemented by a SAPI client application to receive notifications."

I'll update the response to include a sample.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes possible to compile my program. But I have (a last) problem. When I create an object of CSpeechHandler on main.cpp writing "CSpeechHandler* cs= new CSpeechHandler();" MY program doesn't do anything. And if I try to call the function 
"cs->SetupTTSHandlers();" (To do this I have had to make SetupTTSHandlers public) It speaks but never calls the NotifyCallback function. So how to iniziate that calls? PD: I have introduce on the example "hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&m_spVoice);" in order to make it runs

Comment: The sample I posted isn't complete.  There's a complete worked example of TTS events in the Windows 7 SDK (and almost certainly in the Windows Vista SDK as well) - look in %windowssdkdir%\Samples\winui\speech\ttsapplication.  That app uses SetNotifyWindowsMessage, but I changed it to use SetNotifyCallbackInterface without any difficulty.

Comment: I know about that example, but it contains a lot of windows stuff (I don't use windows, I use a Win32 console aplication) and I can't see how to make the events start "NotifyCallback" on an automatic way. I don't see it. PD: When I have work on C++, I have always work with sequential programs...so It's difficult to me

Comment: Thanks for all, but any new suggestion?

Comment: You're not pumping messages (which are needed to get callbacks) while the speech is processing.  I've edited the source code to provide a complete working example with events.

Comment: Thanks you very much. You are an anonymous hero of the contemporany age. You have saved me from being lost a lot of hours.
Thanks again.